# Use different css based on parent's class?

Tags: html, css

I realize that my question is horribly worded. That being said, I'm unsure of the correct terminology to express my question. I'll try as best as I can...

Is it possible to use different css styles based on what classes the containing element has?

E.g.

```
<div class="blue">
    <a class="text">Hello</a>
</div>

<div class="red">
    <a class="text">Hello</a>
</div>
```

In the example above the "Hello"s should be blue and red respectively, but they should inherit their color from their "text" class, not from the "red" or "blue" class. Basically, I want to have two "text" classes, and the one which is used depends on the class of the containing element. Can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
.blue .text {
     color:#00F;
}

.red .text {
     color:#F00;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrVZT/)

Comment: Thank you! What if I wanted to have multiple classes per... parent class I guess you could call it? E.g. text_a text_b

Comment: Then just do `.blue .text_a {...}` and `.blue .text_b {...}`

Comment: I was hoping there was an alternate to having to put ".blue" or ".red" before every ".text_a"...".text_b"...etc. but I guess I'll live. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Joren already answered your original question, although I might add that in addition to ".blue .text" and ".red .text", you can also have just a ".text" class to define what styles you want both colors to have (i.e. font size, font family).

```
.blue .text {
   color:#00F;
}
.red .text {
   color:#F00;
}
.text {
    // whatever styles you want both the blue and red sections to have
}
```

As for your next question: "What if I wanted to have multiple classes per... parent class I guess you could call it? E.g. text_a text_b"....

```
// custom styles for "blue" subclasses
.blue .text_a {}
.blue .text_b {}
.blue .text_c {}

// custom styles for "red" subclasses
.red .text_a {}
.red .text_b {}
.red .text_c {}

// what you want each subclass to have regardless of whether they're blue or red
.text_a {}
.text_b {}
.text_c {}
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: yep... I was hoping there was an alternate to having to put ".blue" or ".red" before every ".text_a"...".text_b"...etc. but I guess I'll live. Thanks for the help!